# wpf autocompletebox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, autocompletebox

I've created some UserControls which are wrapping some standard controls, for example: a textbox/combobox + Image + textblock. I'm trying to do the same thing with AutoCompleteBox and have failed so far... 
The list of items is shown fine, I can select na item, but that doesn't trigger a change to the SelectedItem. I'm using almost the same code for combobox so not sure what's wrong...

Anyway I've played around with ValueMemberPath / ValueMemberBinding on the AutoCompleteBox but not sure if that's the way to go.

The UserControl xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ACProperty, Path=ImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30" Margin="1" Grid.Column="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ACProperty, Path=Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" />
        </Grid>

        <toolkitInput:AutoCompleteBox FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ACProperty, Path=ItemsSource}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ACProperty, Path=SelectedItem}"
                                      MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                      MinimumPopulateDelay="300"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,1,2,1" />

    </Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public static DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Label", typeof(string), typeof(AutoCompleteProperty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(AutoCompleteProperty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(AutoCompleteProperty),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    public static DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(AutoCompleteProperty));

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
        }

    }

    public string ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
        }

    }
```

And in a UserControl/Window where I would like to use it:

```
<cont:AutoCompleteProperty Label="Product Category"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductCategories}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProductCategory}"
                            ImageSource="..."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated binding in the following code....

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Height="350" Width="525"
             xmlns:toolkitInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
             x:Name="root"
             >
    <Grid>![enter image description here][1]
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,ElementName=root}" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="100" Margin="1" Grid.Column="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label,ElementName=root}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" />
        </Grid>

        <toolkitInput:AutoCompleteBox FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,ElementName=root}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=root}"
                                      MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                      MinimumPopulateDelay="300"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,1,2,1" />

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Here is a image of the window using the above code
[image: Here is a image of the window using the above code]

Comment: Thanks for all your help but actually it was something else, setting the SelectedItem binding mode to TwoWay did the trick, altough I'm not sure why if in the code behind the BindsTwoWayByDefault is set to True... marked as answer for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in your bindings.

Observe usercontrol DataContext.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.AutoCompleteProperty"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:toolkitInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="100" Margin="1" Grid.Column="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100" />
        </Grid>

        <toolkitInput:AutoCompleteBox FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                                      MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                      MinimumPopulateDelay="300"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,1,2,1" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and no changes in code behind file

Comment: Nice try but with the DataContext set the popup list doesn't even appear I'm afraid.